# Truncate file openned with SDL RWops

Tags: sqlite, sdl, truncate, vfs

I'm trying to write SQLite VFS which will use RWops from SDL2. While my current task is to read database from android assets, I also plan to support writing.

While SDL implement some basic I/O (`read`/`write`/`tell`/`seek`), there is no `truncate` function, which is used by SQLite.

Is there any way to work-around this?

Comment: Well, it's not like you can implement `xSync` either :)  Perhaps issue a `seek` to the truncated size & keep a note of the "current file size" around for actual system-level truncation later during `SDL_RWclose()`?

Comment: @genpfault `xSync` is something which can be safely no-oped with note in docs (file locks aren't that cross-platform). Idea wtith writing some kind of custom header/footer with actual size looks promising, but it will make database incompatible with default sqlite format and keep file bigger than required.